# Tensorflow 2 migrating estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow.net

There are some high level API's in Tensorflow 1 called Estimators. It's a collection of common ML algorithms. However, in the documentation it is stated that Estimators are not recommended for new code.

Where can I find the improved versions of these common ML algorithms? I am specifically interested in:

- tf.compat.v1.estimator.LinearRegressor
- tf.compat.v1.estimator.DNNRegressor
- tf.compat.v1.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor

Comment: The recommended way is to use keras. You can have a look at the guide: [Migrate from Estimator to Keras APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_estimator)

Comment: The migration guide doesn't tell me how to implement the algorithms I want to use